# Community Promotion Ads — 2020

Tags: discussion, community-ads

You lost your “beta” label in 2019, so welcome to your very first edition of **Community Promotion Ads**, for the year of 2020!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/559).

Comment: Upvote this comment if you wish this site to show **no community ads** at all. (I cannot post it as an answer because of the stated rules.)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Why is it that you do not want any ads at all?

Comment: @user1271772 They are distracting. I don't find any of these projects so important that I need to be reminded of them every time I visit the site. I don't want to open the door to the concept of "acceptable ads". And why is it that you *do* want ads, if I may ask?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: (1) I have never actually seen one of these ads. So they have never distracted me. I do not see any ad over here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/. Do you? Yet apparently each ad on that site is being clicked about 2 times/day: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/4653. (2) You ask why I want an ad, well community promotion ads have been going on for several years across all the graduated SE sites, so it seems not many people have a problem with it. For me, it would help to get more people committed to my Area51 proposal, which is very very very hard :)

Comment: @user1271772 There is a [reduced ads](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) privilege on some SE sites (but I don't see it on chemistry.se; I am not sure if it does not exist or if it is hidden); maybe you have it. I am not an expert in that area, but I do not trust ad-click statistics at all; there is a lot of noise (search engine crawlers, bots, etc.) and fudging going on in that industry. Good luck with your proposal, but thanks, I have already seen it in this thread and I would prefer *not* to have it cluttering other pages I see on SE. Once is enough.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, in the link you sent, it says "The areas in red are the leaderboard ads. The areas in gray are the sidebar ads, which will remain visible" so the reduced ads privilege is not for these "community ads". Anyway, I see that you don't like ads. Do remember that Computational Science SE would not exist if it wasn't advertised widely during its Area51 days. Perhaps you will just have to learn to ignore the ads, or get an ad blocker (they actually do work for these sidebar ads such as the one I proposed below), or **campaign more for the ads on SEs to be removed.**

Answer (score 10):

[image: Common topics on Matter Modeling SE]

Comment: For the design of new materials: solar cells, photovoltaics, bio-materials, organic LEDs for smartphone screens (same brightness while being less susceptible to cracking), new materials for better batteries, energy storage materials, stronger glass for windows and better heat insulation, molecular magnets, energy conversion materials, superconductors for quantum computing, better semi-conductors for computer hardware, stronger and lighter materials for cars, bikes, planes, spaceships, etc.